# Why does my Tkinter Scrollbar's bar fill entire length of my window?

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

I have working horizontal scrollbar, but for some reason it does not rezise the "visible" bar. It does scroll perfectly, but I even didin't notice there was a bar before I added style `clam`.

[image: Numbers go up to "a99"]

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()

style = ttk.Style()
style.theme_use('clam')

main_frame = Frame(root)
main_frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

my_canvas = Canvas(main_frame)
my_canvas.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=1)

my_scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(main_frame, orient=HORIZONTAL, command=my_canvas.xview)
my_scrollbar.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)

my_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=my_scrollbar.set)
my_canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: my_canvas.configure(scrollregion=my_canvas.bbox("all")))

seccond_frame = Frame(my_canvas)

my_canvas.create_window((0,0), window=seccond_frame, anchor="nw")

for i in range(100):
    Label(seccond_frame, text=f"a{i}").grid(row=0, column=i)

root.update()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues in your code:

1. `my_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=my_scrollbar.set)` should be `my_canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=my_scrollbar.set)`
2. when adding items to `seccond_frame`, it is `seccond_frame` get resized, not `my_canvas`. So you need to bind `<Configure>` on `seccond_frame` instead of `my_canvas`

Comment: In this particular case it seems that 1st issue fixed the problem entirely. I didin't notice any difference after "fixing" 2nd issue. Anyway problem is solved and I thank you! I new it had to be something as simple as that, but just could not see it even after few hours :|

Comment: You can see the difference when you try to add more and more items to `seccond_frame` after the program starts.

Comment: Ah. Thats why I did not notice it. In my program number of items is fixed.

Comment: If the number of items is fixed, you don't need to bind `<Configure>` at all and just update the `scrollregion` between the last 2 lines: `root.update()` and `root.mainloop()`.